# zombie lxc swap file: text file busy but no pid

Tags: ubuntu, lxc, pid, deleting

I have a server running Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (Precise Pangolin). On that server I created a new Linux container:

```
$ sudo lxc-create -n mycontainer
```

After a while I decided to get rid of this container:

```
$ sudo lxc-destroy -n mycontainer
```

However I got the following error:

```
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/rootfs/swapfile': Operation not permitted
```

I tried to delete the offending file manually:

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/rootfs/swapfile
```

But, sure enough, this gave me the same error message.

I checked the extended file attributes with lsattr to make sure it wasn't immutable:

```
$ sudo lsattr /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/rootfs/swapfile
-------------e- /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/rootfs/swapfile
```

As an experiment I tried to overwrite the file:

```
$ echo '' > /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/rootfs/swapfile
```

This gave me a new error message:

```
bash: /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/rootfs/swapfile: Text file busy
```

So I tried to use lsof to get the pid of the process which is using the file:

```
$ sudo lsof /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/rootfs/swapfile
```

This produced no output. I tried the same thing with fuser:

```
$ sudo fuser /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/rootfs/swapfile
```

Again, no output.

I'll also mention that I checked the size of the file:

```
$ sudo du -h /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/rootfs/swapfile
1.1G    /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/rootfs/swapfile
```

What's going on here and how do I get rid of this file?

Comment: Um, did you try `swapoff`?

Comment: Well that did the trick. I didn't even know that that existed. I don't suppose you could hazard a guess as to why this happened? Or why I couldn't find an associated PID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name `swapfile` gives a very strong hint as to the file's purpose and what is using it.

That is: The system is using it as swap, because someone created the swap file and added it to the system with `swapon`.

Try removing it from active swap with `swapoff`:

```
swapoff /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/rootfs/swapfile
```